# Como organizar los paneles en un JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe

quiero saber la manera de poder colocar asi los paneles sobre un JFrame.

No veo la manera de hacerlo o talvez estoy ignorando algo ya que solo se lo mas basico de layouts y voy empezando.

Muchas gracias

[image: Este diseño]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Considera un [*BorderLayout*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#border).